# Error displaying files in Hadoop filesystem on standard output using FileSystem directly

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm new to Hadoop and was trying to display file contents in Hadoop filesystem on standard output using the FileSystem directly but am getting the below error.

```html
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;


public class FileSystemCat {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   Configuration conf = new Configuration();
      conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
      conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));
    String uri = "/books/pg5000.txt";
  FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
  InputStream in = null;
  try {
   in = fs.open(new Path(uri));
   IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
   } finally {
   IOUtils.closeStream(in);
   }
  }
}
```

Error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosName.<clinit>(KerberosName.java:43)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:748)
    at 

    org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:621)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2753)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2745)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:354)
        at FileSystemCat.main(FileSystemCat.java:17)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 13 more
```

Can someone guide me, where am I wrong?

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory - Is log4j present at runtime?

Comment: Yes it's jar is added

Comment: Anyway, the exception tells it cannot find the org.slf4j.LoggerFactory class. So at runtime your jar is not available in the used classloader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

This error occurs if you do not have `slf4j-api-x.x.x` in your classpath. Try to add this jar in your classpath first. This jar can be found in `$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib` (my hadoop version is 2.6.0).

You could also try this:

```
java -cp /path/to/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-x.x.x.jar:. yourjavaclassname
```

Comment: Thanks! slf4j-api-x.x.x jar was missing. Added and it worked.